# If $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 =4$ and $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 8$ then find $a^4+b^4+c^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetric-polynomials

This is a popular question, but I can find $a^4+b^4+c^4$ if I know $a+b+c, a^2+b^2+c^2, a^3 +b^3 +c^3$ or in special case $a+b+c=0$ we only need a more condition like $a+b+c$. I have tried in many times and can't find out the way to archive it.

Comment: Well easy to see $a=0,b=0,c=2$ satisfies hence $a^4+b^4+c^4=16$ but we have to prove that this is the only solution which i doubt is true

Comment: we need one more equation to find the value of $a^4+b^4+c^4$

Comment: If you want solutions in $\mathbb{N}$, then the solution of @Albus Dumbledore ist the only one.

Comment: We don't need more equations, nor do we need to stay in $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it sounds logical that we need three equations, because three variables and stuff. This is **wrong**, though. Sometimes one equation can give us two variables, like $x^2+y^2=0\Rightarrow x=0,\;y=0$ (if we stay in $\mathbb R$, that is; but if we don't, then the original question can't be answered either). Same thing here.

Obviously†, $a^3+b^3+c^3\leqslant(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{3/2}$, and the equality is only possible when two of the variables are $0$. So $(0,0,2)$ and its permutations are indeed the only real solutions, from where you can easily find the answer.

So it goes.

---

†
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\geqslant \overbrace{a^6+b^6+c^6+\underbrace{a^4b^2+a^2b^4}_\text{apply AM-GM}+\underbrace{b^4c^2+b^2c^4}_\text{here too}+\underbrace{a^4c^2+a^2c^4}_\text{and here}}^\text{skipped quite a lot of terms, all of them quadratic}\geqslant \\\geqslant a^6+b^6+c^6+2a^3b^3+2b^3c^3+2a^3c^3=(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2,\text{ hence}\\
a^3+b^3+c^3\leqslant (a^2+b^2+c^2)^{3/2}=4^{3/2}=8$$

Comment: This is nicely done!(+1)  i gave up on this question without even trying as i thought information was inadequate,got to see that i am wrong

Comment: Brilliant! This method will fit for high school students.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simpler solution is given by Lagrange multipliers. The stationary points of $f(a,b,c)=a^3+b^3+c^3$ over $a^2+b^2+c^2=4$ occur where $3(a^2,b^2,c^2)=2\lambda(a,b,c)$, i.e. at $\pm\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ and at the permutations of $\pm(0,0,2)$ and $\pm(0,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$. In particular
$$ \max_{a^2+b^2+c^2}a^3+b^3+c^3 = 8 $$
and in a point of absolute maximum we have $a^4+b^4+c^4=16$.

Comment: Thanks Jack, this way fit for college students. Your answer suggested me a effective method to find max, min for questions like that.